# angular2 can't import ng2-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I can't import ng2-bootstrap

layout.jade

```
html
 head
title Angular 2 QuickStart
// 1. Load libraries

script(src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js")
script(src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js")
//script(src="/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js")
script(src="/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js")
script(src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js")

// 2. Configure SystemJS
script.
  System.config({
      packages: {
         app: {
            //format: 'register',
            //defaultExtension: 'js',
            defaultJSExtensions: true
        }
      },
          paths: {
          'ng2-bootstrap/*': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/*.js'
          }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
// 3. Display the application
body
    my-app Loading...
```

express

```
 app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

app.component.ts

```
 //import "ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap";

   import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
   import {Alert} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
   import {firstComponent} from './component/first.component';

   @Component({
     //directives: [Alert],
      directives: [firstComponent,Alert],
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
        <h2> helllo</h2>
        <first></first>
        <alert type="info">ng2-bootstrap hello!</alert>
        `
    })
    export class AppComponent { }
```

error console

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/accordion/accordion 404 (Not Found)
```

```
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-
```

and also more errors the same as that re: cannot import component?

Comment: ng2-bootstrap, was renamed to ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue myself and found this link helpful: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/50#issuecomment-165448962

A snippet of the most relevant code:

System.JS config:

```
System.config({
   packages: {
     "app": {
        "defaultExtension": "js"
     },
     "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap": {
        "defaultExtension": "js"
     }
  },
  paths: {
    "ng2-bootstrap":   "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap"
  }
});
```

You can then simply import it like so:

```
import { Progressbar } from "ng2-bootstrap";
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    directives: [
        Progressbar
    ],
    template: "<progressbar></progressbar>" 
})
```

Hope this helps you, like it did to me.

Comment: Hi, I'm using webpack,  where can I find the System.JS file?

Comment: @antonio It's named `system-config.ts`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me.
Under the systemjs.config file:

```
map: {
'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js',
       'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment.js'
    }
```

We need to mention the 'moment' because ng2-bootstrap is importing moment.

And in the app.modules, just do the following:

```
import {DatepickerModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
```

And also the following:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ....,
        ....,
        DatepickerModule
    ],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: great analysis, adding moment and keeping the rest of the lines as it is helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the current answers are satisfactory since they do fighting symptoms and do not solve the underlying problem.

What I did to solve this:

```
System.config({
    baseURL: '/node_modules',
    "defaultJSExtensions": true,
    map: {
      app: '/app/'
    }
    paths: {
      "moment":   "moment/moment"
    }
  });
```

Line 1: So I set `node_modules` my base url, so I don't have to rewrite every import on a package by package basis.

Line 2: Then I tell systemjs to look for JS files by default.

Line 3 - 5: I map everything that starts with app to the app directory. So SystemJs won't try to find my own files in the /node_modules folder.

Finished.

On Line 6 - 7 One 'bugfix' had to be done when SystemJS tried to load momentjs directly from /node_modules/, so i set it to its own directory. Weird..

Answer (score 1):

I am using the latest version of angular-cli 2.4.7 (webpack) and was able to get it to work.

Run this in your angular app

```
npm install ng2-bootstrap bootstrap moment --save
```

Open the following files and add them as listed

Insert a new entry into the styles array

```
  # angular-cli.json
  "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ]
```

Import desired module

```
# src/app/app.module.ts
...
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
....
,
  imports: [
DatepickerModule.forRoot(),
...
]
...})
```

And you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
                        **>-------- NG2BOOTSTRAP--------->**
```

Use these commands to add these dependencies to your package.json

1. npm install moment --save
2. npm install ng2-bootstrap --save

Modify your System.config.js to the following code as this map tells the System loader where to look for code.

```
var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
     moment:              'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
    'ng2-bootstrap':              'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap',
  };

var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',    defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-bootstrap':          {defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
```

Add Bootstrap to your index.html
`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

App.module.ts
import { Ng2BootstrapModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
And, add Ng2BootstrapModule to imports of @NgModule.

Then, U are good to go for ng2Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi, I'm using webpack, where can I find the System.config.js file?

Answer (score 0):

In `systemjs.config.js` packages variable, add the following for the fix the issue

```
'ng2-bootstrap':
{
    format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update the systemjs.config.js package variable with the following and error will be gone
'ng2-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },// AND THIS