# Angular 2 - Import external libraries for both JIT and AoT

Tags: angular, systemjs, rollupjs, angular2-aot

I'm trying to configure my codebase to be able to do both JiT and AoT so that I can use JiT for local development and AoT for production. I've followed the [angular documentation here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) and have successfully gotten both to work individually.

The problem that I'm facing is when I try to import external libraries, specifically moment-js.

For JiT, I'm using SystemJS, the configuration for which is

```
// systemjs.config.js

System.config({
    map: {
        // ...
        moment: '/node_modules/moment',
    },
    packages: {
        // ...
        moment: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

And then to import in a component in typescript, I can just do

```
// some-component.component.ts

import * as moment from 'moment/moment';
```

This works just fine for local development.

When I try to AoT compile with rollup however, I get a `Cannot call a namespace ('moment')` compilation error. I solved that problem following [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519823/using-rollup-for-angular-2s-aot-compiler-and-importing-moment-js), so after a couple changes to the rollup config, the import statement in the component should be

```
// some-component.component.ts

import moment from 'moment';
```

Which works great for AoT and rollup, but now SystemJS has a problem understanding that.

I can't seem to break out of the loop. I can get one to work, but not both at the same time. Is there any way to get SystemJS to understand the import statements required by rollup? I don't think its possible the other way around.

**EDIT**:

I did find a way to at least make it work, but it's not exactly ideal. Instead of importing it, I just declared it as `any` and then load in the library externally with a script tag. So now the component is

```
// some-component.component.ts

declare const moment: any;
```

As I said, this is not ideal since this doesn't allow me to bundle moment in with the AoT build, and it also forces typescript to interpret the 'moment' var as `any` so now it doesn't know about its type. So this still doesn't exactly answer my question, but this does at least work.

Comment: I'm the OP of the thread you mentioned. Did you manage to find a better way to do it? I'm curious as to why nobody seems to talk about this, it is quite a serious limitation...

Comment: Unfortunately no. My only dependency on that particular project was moment, so I decided to just live with my hacky solution since I couldn't find any other way to do it. I considered other options like trying to use environment variables to control which import statement is used, but I never tried it. I also wondered if webpack could handle the AoT like imports, but again, never tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep import:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

And add plugin to rollup.js:

```
{
    name: 'replace moment imports',
    transform: code => ({
        code: code.replace(/import\s*\*\s*as\s*moment/g, 'import moment'),
        map: { mappings: '' }
    })
},
```

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question.

Comment: Have you red question above? It's not a duplicate at all - just can be solved similar way.

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not wish to add a custom rollup.js plugin, or are using a packaging tool like `ng-packagr`, consider replacing your import statement to the following solution:

```
import * as momentImported from 'moment'; 
const moment = momentImported;
```

---

This solution was originally provided by the following Github issue:
https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/217#issuecomment-339460255